# How to force android to reload main.xml

Tags: android, configuration, locale

I'm working on a project to change locale on fly in application. The main UI was created in res/layout/main.xml. Here is my code:

```
OnCreate() 
{
           ... ...
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = Locale.FRANCE;  // set locale to french
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Result:
android:text="@string/myString" in main.xml is using myString in res/values-fr/strings.xml that is what I expected.

In another function in which locale gets changed to Italian:

```
{   ... ...
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = Locale.ITALY;   // change locale to Italian
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

After that function called, getString(R.string.myString) is using myString in res/values-it/strings.xml that is what I expected.
But, main UI doesn't change. android:text="@string/myString" in main.xml is still using myString in res/values-fr/strings.xml until I force the Activity to restart with:

```
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I tried to call view.invalidate() and layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, this) but none of them works. Any idea/suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I don't get why you change Locale manually. I mean if you create value-fr and value-it folders in your resource folder, the language will automatically switch related to the device configuration. This is not a good practice in my opinion. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html
Looking at how the activity life cycle works, I don't think it's possible to do. 
Maybe you could try Viewgroup.invalidate()

Comment: You should probably use Fragments. Your main.xml would be a fragment container, and then you use Fragment Transactions to switch different fragments in/out of the Fragment container

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, when ready for updates, make sure your onCreate method can handle them properly, then call [recreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate%28%29) on your activity and Android will care about recreation and call the flow as usual.

Comment: I'm working on 2.3 level 10 but this function was introduced since level 11. So... Thank you anyway.

Comment: May be this will help to understand how Android does it now? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.recreate%28%29

Answer (score 0):

I'm really curious why you are changing the locale manually since it can be driven automatically from device settings, but let's pretend you have done it intentionally :)

What you need to do - is just call `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. Activity will update UI automatically based on locale settings.

The tricky point here - is that if you have some dynamic data (such as references to buttons, text views, etc), you might need to update your references as well, since old ones will not be relevant any longer.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this really needs to reset all dynamic data. I was trying to find a simple way (hope there is) to redraw the views.

Comment: Besides restart, this is the only way works for me. But the problem is that calling setContentView() multiple time cause memory leak. In my case, I cound switch languages 6 times then system died due to out of memory. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, it is really hard to say w/o seeing the code. Do you allocate any Bitmaps when you switch languages?

Answer (score 0):

The code used to change locale is better to move to your custom Application class. You create something like MyApplication which extends Application in onCreate/onConfiguration changes will be code like this:

```
String lang = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_APP, 0).getString(LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
locale = new Locale(lang);
if (locale != null) {
 newConfig.locale = locale;
 Locale.setDefault(locale);
 getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

You register this custom class in AndroidManifest section Application (      android:name=".MyApplication")
The idea is that Android doesn't like to set different locale that is set in system.
In your settings activity do this after locale change:

```
Configuration c = new Configuration();
Locale newLocale = new Locale(localeCode);
Locale.setDefault(newLocale);
c.locale = newLocale;
ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(c, ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

And then restart/go back to your MainActivity like this:

```
Intent goTo = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
goTo.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
act.startActivity(goTo);
```

I hope that I didn't miss something important, but this is the main idea behind changing language dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, this is the only way I found that works. But it'll restart the activity and in my case will re-init network connection and database and take long time.

Comment: In this case don't see any way out how to reload main.xml withnout restarting the Activity. Maybe hold the reference of network thread in MyApplication or even create connection in onCreate in MyApplication. It's dirty way, but it can work.